# Euler method for second order ODE

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, numerical-methods

"
1. Write this second order ode as a first order ode.

$y''(t)=y(t)+y'(t)+t$

$y(0) = 1$

$y'(0) = 0$

2. Use the Euler Method with h = 0.1. What approximation of $(y(h), y'(h))$ do you get?"

I think I understand the first problem. I substitute y with $u_1$ and $y'$ with $u_2$ which gives: $y' = u_2, y''=u_1 + u_2 + t$. Is that correct?

If so, I don't really know where to go from there.

Comment: Yes, but write $y'' = u_2'$ to get the first order system: $y' = u_2$ and $u_2' = y + u_2 + t$. Now apply Euler's method one step: $y(h) = y(0) + h u_2(0)$ and $u_2(h) = u_2(0) + h[y(0) + u_2(0) + 0)]$.

Comment: Unfortunately it wasn't a typo as much as me not understanding... Why don't I write it the way I did? That's how I interpret one should do it from my textbook.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

*Expanding the comment of Winther:* Yes, but write $y''=u_2'$ to get the first order system: 
\begin{align}
u_1'&=u_2&\text{ and }\\
u_2'&=u_1+u_2+t.
\end{align}
Now apply Euler's method one step: 
\begin{align}
y(h)=u_1(h)&\approx u_1(0)+h\,u_2(0)&&=1+h\cdot0&\text{ and }\\
y'(h)=u_2(h)&\approx u_2(0)+h\,\bigl[u_1(0)+u_2(0)+0\bigr]&&=0+h⋅[1+0+0].
\end{align}

In the next step you would get
\begin{align}
y(2h)=u_1(2h)&\approx u_1(h)+h\,u_2(h)&&≈1+h\cdot h&\text{ and }\\
y'(2h)=u_2(2h)&\approx u_2(h)+h\,\bigl[u_1(h)+u_2(h)+h\bigr]&&≈h+h⋅[1+h+h].
\end{align}
et

Comment: Thanks for a great answer! However, I'm not completely sure what you're doing when applying the Euler's method. The only way I know how to do it is: $Y_n = Y_{n-1} + hf(x_{n-1}, y_{n-1})$. Is that what you're doing here but just differently so I don't see it?

Comment: Yes, that is what happens when $Y_k=\pmatrix{u_{1,k}\\u_{2,k}}$ are vectors and $f(x,Y)$ is a vector-valued function that returns vectors of the same vector space. Then if you write the equations component-wise something like in the answer results.

Comment: Hmm, I think I'm starting to get it now. If it's not to much to ask (I'm very grateful for your help), would you mind putting numbers instead of "letters" into your answer? Would like to compare that because I'm quite not getting the answer the way I want it to so I feel that could help.

Comment: Okay, I think the problem now is that I don't really get how the vector is used. I get that $y(h)$ is equal to $u_1(0)$ + its derivative. And I also get that $y'(h)$ is equal to its derivative. This gives me the equation: $u_1(h) = u_1(0) + h[u_1(0) + u_2(0) + t] $which unfortunately gives me the wrong answer when doing: $u_1(h) = 1 + 0.1[1 + 0 + t]$. What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Thank you again for a great answer. I think I might start to understand what's going on. The problem is though that I get the answer $(1, 0, 0.1)$ when trying your solution but it's supposed to be $(1, 0, 1)$. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Is there some confusion with decimal dot and decimal comma? The result should be a 2D vector, not a 3D vector.

Comment: oh my... You're right. It's actually (1, 0.1). Pretty bad quality on the question so that's why... Thanks a lot for your help!